# Android getCacheDir in AsyncTask

Tags: android, caching, android-activity, android-asynctask

Can I use getCacheDir() only in a class that extends Activity? I would like to use it in an AsyncTask so that I can do the time intensive cache file saving in it.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Pass it to your AsyncTask constructor
- make it static variable